# How can I create a new Azure VM in an existing cloud service with knife azure (Chef)?

Tags: azure, chef, knife

I have tried using the "--azure-connect-to-existing-dns" parameter but that doesn't work.

I'd like to create Azure VM's, but have them inside an already existing cloud service instead of creating a new cloud service for each new VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a newly created VM to an existing cloud service when using the "**knife azure server create**" command, you need to use both of the following two parameters:

**--azure-connect-to-existing-dns mycloudservice**

**--azure-dns-name mycloudservice**

...where "mycloudservice" is your existing cloud service's DNS name.